# How can I improve my code for monkey_trouble codingbat problem

Tags: python

We have two monkeys, a and b, and the parameters a_smile and b_smile indicate if each is smiling. We are in trouble if they are both smiling or if neither of them is smiling. Return True if we are in trouble.

My solution was this, I was able to solve this problem quite quick actually. Before, when I would try these I couldn't do a single one, but, I've been getting better, but, I still know I suck. :\

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
  if a_smile and b_smile:
    return True
  if not a_smile and b_smile:
    return False
  if not a_smile and not b_smile:
    return True
  if a_smile and not b_smile:
    return False
```

I saw a solution like this:

```
if a_smile==b_smile:
    return True
  return False
```

and I don't quite understand it.

I get it for, if a_smile==b_smile -> return true.

and then if not a_smile and not b_smile: -> return true

but for the ones where the is if not for only one of the smiles, I don't understand how that code works.

Answer (score 0):

If 'a' and 'b' smiles are equal, it will return True. So that means if both smiles are True, it will return True and also if both smiles are False, it will return True.

But if they are not equal (meaning one is True and the other one is False), it will not run the program in the if statement, so the program continues and returns False.

This does the same thing as their script, but I just added an else statement to make it easier to understand:

```
if a_smile == b_smile:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just started to be able to solve these kinds of problems without help from internet, and I wish I had the ability to think more like this naturally, it's getting better but I must practice more.

Comment: @debloatgod as you said, just practice and practice and soon you'll see that the problems you couldn't figure out before will become easier and easier to solve. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If the smiles are Boolean (`True` or `False`), then `a_smile == b_smile` is equivalent to:

```
(0 == 0) or (1 == 1)
```

...which is the same as:

```
if (not a_smile and not b_smile) or (a_smile and b_smile):
    return True
```

The other option is `a_smile != b_smile`, which is the same as:

```
(0 != 1) or (1 != 0)
```

Again, this can be decomposed into:

```
if (not a_smile and b_smile) or (a_smile and not b_smile):
    return False
```

Finally, we have:

```
if (not a_smile and not b_smile) or (a_smile and b_smile):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Hey, this actually covers all four cases! Your original code can also be simplified to the above one, which is equivalent to the code with `==`.

---

Also notice how you can interpret the text of the task in a different way:

> We are in trouble if they are both smiling or if neither of them is smiling. Return True if we are in trouble.

So, we return `True` if moth monkeys have the same "smiling status". Thus:

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
    return a_smile == b_smile # is the "smiling status" the same?
```

...which is again equivalent to your original code, the second code in your post *and* the code after "Finally, we have" in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `a_smile` and `b_smile` are boolean values, then a value of `True` indicates a smile, and `False` indicates not smiling.

The `==` operator checks if the left value is equal to the right one, thus checking the condition if both monkeys are smiling or both not smiling. It doesn't only compare in case of a positive value.

```py
if a_smile==b_smile:
    return True
```

We can deduct from this that if the values are not equal (`else`), then we are safe:

```py
return False
```

*Notice that we do not need to write `else` because of the return in the line before.

Now we should note that a condition eventually evaluates as a boolean value. This means we can simplify the code even further:

```
def monkey_trouble(a_smile, b_smile):
    return a_smile == b_smile
```